# How to let users broadcast themselves from my web application? (Ustream, Dacast

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming, twitch, broadcasting

**I am trying to add a feature where some users (say admins) would be able to broadcast themselves from their profile page.**

I wish to provide an embedded player where other users can watch these admins. Most of the solutions I looked at does not allow multiple simultaneous channels/streams.

What is the best tool to achieve this?

Thanks!

---

Some solutions I looked at:

**Ustream**: Doesn't allow multiple streams even for their paid plans. [Max 3 channels for $999/month](https://www.ustream.tv/platform/plans/pro-broadcasting)

**DaCast**: Allows multiple streams but requires users to download a flash based player and authenticate seperately for each stream. This is even bigger problem if admins are streaming from their phones!

**Meerkat**: Doesn't allow multiple streams.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube allows multiple streams, each embed-able, and uses HTML5 player.

Hope this helps.